# ShouldQueue and Queueable in Listeners Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

- Laravel Version: 5.3
- PHP Version: 7.1
- Redis Queue

#### Description:

Hello to everyone.
I have an event with several Listeners. The ShouldQueue interface work well on Listeners,
but the listeners can't work with Queueable trait (delay, different queue),
is this a bug or a feature?

I know that I can use jobs for delaying. But in my perspective, every class that allows to implement ShouldQueue  should also work with  Queueable (the ability to be delayed).